# Splitting a list of dates/weeks into a and b weeks with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

The datesList in the query is just a list of datetime values.

With the linq query/groupby I group all those days belonging to a certain week in the year into a Grouping.

```
Func<DateTime, int> weekProjector = d =>
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear( d, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);

var weeks = (from date in datesList group date by weekProjector(date.Date)).ToList();
```

Lets assume the weeks collection contains 8 and can rotate by A and B weeks. That means a rotation by value 2 delivers this result if the user starts with A weeks:

A A , B B, A A, B B (8 weeks and weekly rotation is 2)

A A A A, B B B B (8 weeks and weekly rotation is 4)

How can I query the weeks collection and group/project or whatever the datetime values into a separate weekListA/weekListB with considering the rotation value which can be any number from 1 to 8.

UPDATE:

The final state are 2 List A and B list which each contains datetime values from the weeks collection.

UPDATE 2: In this sample the weekly rotation would have the factor 4: That means I have 4 weeks of type A, 4 weeks of type B and so on

[image]

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding your question. Could you perhaps give a more complete example of exactly what you wish to achieve, showing both the initial and final state of the week set?

Comment: What are A- and B-Weeks?

Comment: @Tim When the weeks collection have 4 week groupings and the week rotation value is 2 then the first 2 weeks are A-weeks and the last 2 weeks are B-weeks. I thought this is clear from my sample above. I hope its clear now :)

Comment: @LeviBotelho I have done some comments + update. Any questions else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly.

Given a bunch of dates, grouped by the week of the year:

```
// some testdata
var datesList = Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select (e => DateTime.Now.AddDays(7 * e)).ToList();

Func<DateTime, int> weekProjector = d =>
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(d, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);

var weeks = datesList.GroupBy(weekProjector).ToList();
```

you should get the result you want by this query:

```
var result = weeks.OrderBy(w => w.Key)
                  .Select((g, i) => new {WeekType = (i / rotation) % 2, Week = g})
                  .GroupBy(w => w.WeekType)
                  .ToList();
```

where `rotation` is your "rotation" (`2` or `4`), and `2` is the number of groups you want (groups `A` and `B` => 2 groups).

You maybe want to add to a `Select` after the `GroupBy` to select only the data you want, e.g.:

```
var weekA = result.Where(r => r.Key==0).Select(g => g).SelectMany(g => g).SelectMany(a => a.Week).ToList();
var weekB = result.Where(r => r.Key==1).Select(g => g).SelectMany(g => g).SelectMany(a => a.Week).ToList();
```

---

A more readable/generic solution:

```
void Rotate<TResult, TGroup>(IEnumerable<TResult> datesList, Func<TResult, TGroup> grouper, int rotation, out List<TResult> listA, out List<TResult> listB)
{
    listA = new List<TResult>();
    listB = new List<TResult>();

    var weeks = datesList.GroupBy(grouper).ToList();

    var c_rotation = 0;
    var c_list = listA;

    using (var en = weeks.GetEnumerator())
        while(en.MoveNext())
        {
            c_list.AddRange((IGrouping<TGroup, TResult>)en.Current);
            c_rotation++;
            if (c_rotation == rotation)
            {
                c_rotation = 0;
                c_list = c_list == listA ? listB : listA;
            }
        }
}
```

Use it like:

```
List<DateTime> listA;
List<DateTime> listB;

Func<DateTime, int> weekProjector = d =>
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(d, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday);

Rotate(datesList, weekProjector, 2, out listA, out listB);
```

Comment: After I have tested Tim`s code I test yours and it worked with rotation 2 and 4 and should so i assume also work with 6 and 8. Congratulation! and thank you. As this is also about learning, do you think SkipWhile with index/rotation could also be helpfull here?

Comment: @Elisa Glad I could help. Please consider voting up :-) I don't think `SkipWhile` would fit here, since its purpose is to skip some items and returning the rest.

Comment: Well skip is to skip the index 0 and 1 for B weeks and skip 2 and 3 for A weeks. I would not say it does not fit. But yeah I upvoted you know :)

Comment: @Elisa For fun, I added are more readable solution using `GetEnumerator()`/`MoveNext()` instead of the second `GroupBy`.

Comment: Actually I find the first solution more readable :P But thanks.

Comment: Hm... maybe it was good that you wrote that 2nd sample because it gave me an idea. I am really thinking about writing a custom collection implementing IEnumerable<T> because there will still be more logic to do. And this way all is encapsulated. If I would use the Rotate method it would be private in my case bad to test only if it would be in sort of a WeekManager class... ok ideas come... hehe

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for, `GroupBy Index % 2`:

```
var abRotations = datesList
    .GroupBy(d => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(d, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday))
    .Select((wg, i) => new { WeekGroup = wg, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index % 2);

List<DateTime> A_Rotation = abRotations.First().SelectMany(x => x.WeekGroup).ToList();
List<DateTime> B_Rotation = abRotations.Last().SelectMany(x => x.WeekGroup).ToList();
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/kpfC5f)

Comment: groupby index module 2 interesting. I thought about SkipeWhile and the index considering with the rotation somehow.

Comment: I have tested your code and its different to my expectation. I will do an update with a deep sample how the output should look like. I also thought you would be using my weeks collection as starting point. I guess you determine the rotation somehow by the Index % 2 right?

Comment: @Elisa: Maybe i've misunderstood the requirement. Post a complete initialized list of `DateTime`s and a desired result. My idea was to group all dates by their week first. Then split these groups into two sub-groups `A_Rotation`+`B_Rotation`. The final result is a `List<DateTime>` for both groups since you have mentioned that: _"The final state are 2 List A and B list which each contains datetime values from the weeks collection."_

Comment: After I tested your code I also tested Dominics code which worked fine. So I take his as solution :) Still thanks for contributing nice to see you had similar ideas in mind hehe.

Comment: I have still put an image with an exact output above. Prolly I should have done that before ;-)

Comment: @Elisa: Why do you show it now? I thought Dominics answer would work as expected. However, if it's getting too abstract i would provide also sample code which initializes the datetimes, then everybody can test it quickly.